# Create a separate unit cls file from an interface

Tags: rhapsody

I have a Rhapsody projects and in a package I have multiple interfaces which are all included in one sbs. I want to extract each interface in its own cls file in a Rhapsody plugin created using the Rhapsody API.

```
IRPUnit unit = cls.getSaveUnit();
       unit.setFilename(cls.getName() + ".cls");
       //unit.setUnitPath(unit.getFullPathName() + "::" + cls.getName()); // Runntime exception
       unit.save(0);
```

It seems that when I set the filename, rhapsody save it as sbs not cls, it saves all the interface deails not per interface.

Answer (score 0):

In Rhapsody the save unit can be the enclosing package or the class itself, depending on some rhapsody options or even package or class option.

cls.setSeparateSaveUnit(true);

should resolve storing everything in the enclosing package and save the class in its own save unit.

see also:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21995358